# How to count contents of last n rows mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to see how many times in the past 7 entries/rows that sleep = 1.

Currently, $num shows the number of times sleep = 1 in all rows. I have seen that 'order by xxx desc limit 7' has been suggested in other answers but it doesn't seem to work well in this scenario. Would greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

Heres my code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE sleep = 1");    
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$num = $row[0];
```

Comment: I assume you have a column storing timestamp in your table? Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table;` and post the result into you question. Also, check MySQL version.

Comment: the answer is already in that `suggested by others`. Just fetch all the last 7 entries, and loop through to check and count `sleep` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM test_table
WHERE sleep = 1
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY COUNT(b) ASC
LIMIT 7
```

Here, **a** is the name of your column you are trying to count 
And, **b** is any column name for usage to count (it can id, or any column name)

Comment: This would be `WHERE sleep = 1` not 7 most recent regardless of `sleep`.

Comment: Isn't that job done by ORDER BY ?

Comment: If is not, could someone explain the question little bit clearer ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32130997/what-does-mysql-perform-first-the-where-clause-or-the-order-by-clause. OP wants `how many times in the past 7 entries` that `sleep = 1`. This would give the last 7 entries that were sleep.... or my interpretation at least.

Comment: ^ yes, this is what I was trying to say. However, I don't feel this link has been able to solve my issue. thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

If the `sleep` is binary/tinyint you can just `sum` that in the query with the `order by`.

```
SELECT sum(sleep)
FROM table
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
LIMIT 7
```

If `sleep` isn't binary you can use a `case` statement.

```
SELECT sum(case when sleep = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as totalsleep
FROM table
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
LIMIT 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea, get all the data in test_table and create a loop that will count the sleep, like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT sleep FROM test_table;");
$x=1;
$sleep = [];
$SleepCount= 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  if($row[0] == "1"){
    $SleepCount++;
  }
  if($x == 7){
     array_push($sleep,$SleepCount);
     $SleepCount = 0;
     $x=0;
  }
   $x++;
}

echo "<pre>",print_r($sleep),"</pre>";
```